# DBT : For loop for 2 variable simultaneously

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

My Sample code is :

```
{%-    set VARIABLE = ["123","1234"]    -%}
{%-    set VARIABLE1 = ["abc","def"]    -%}
with FINAL as (
    
    {% for (col,col1) in (VARIABLE,VARIABLE1) %}

      Select
      current_date as date,
    
       {{ col }} as test1,
       '{{ col1 }}' as test2
     
       UNION ALL
     
    {% endfor %}
  select current_date as date1,
  'Temp' as test1,
  'Temp' as test2
) select * from FINAL
```

Output I am getting :

```
create or replace  view Test.CRS_Foundation.test_for
  
   as (
    with FINAL as (
    
    

      Select
      current_date as date,
    
       123 as test1,
       '1234' as test2
     
       UNION ALL
     
    

      Select
      current_date as date,
    
       abc as test1,
       'def' as test2
     
       UNION ALL
     
    
  select current_date as date1,
  'Temp' as test1,
  'Temp' as test2
) select * from FINAL
  );
```

Expected Output :

```
create or replace  view Test.CRS_Foundation.test_for
  
   as (
    with FINAL as (
    
    

      Select
      current_date as date,
    
       123 as test1,
       'abc' as test2
     
       UNION ALL
     
    

      Select
      current_date as date,
    
       1234 as test1,
       'def' as test2
     
       UNION ALL
     
    
  select current_date as date1,
  'Temp' as test1,
  'Temp' as test2
) select * from FINAL
  );
```

Is there anything i missed in code, code is running fine but output is not as expected
Is there anything i missed in code, code is running fine but output is not as expected
Is there anything i missed in code, code is running fine but output is not as expected

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), which is a function from the Python standard library that takes two sequences and returns a sequence of tuples, with one element from each input sequence. `zip` is available in the dbt jinja context ([docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/zip)).

With `zip`, your code becomes:

```sql
{%-    set VARIABLE = ["123","1234"]    -%}
{%-    set VARIABLE1 = ["abc","def"]    -%}
with FINAL as (
    
    {% for (col,col1) in zip(VARIABLE,VARIABLE1) %}

      Select
      current_date as date,
    
       {{ col }} as test1,
       '{{ col1 }}' as test2
     
       UNION ALL
     
    {% endfor %}
  select current_date as date1,
  'Temp' as test1,
  'Temp' as test2
) select * from FINAL
```